# Extracting personal attributes from text

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, named-entity-extraction

I'd like to extract personal attributes from a text written by a person. e.g.,

> I have always been interested in professional cycling. Being a single mother, it was never easy to find enough time to pursue a sport professionally. The best I could do was to go for short rides along Melbourne's beautiful beaches...

Ideally, I'd want to extract something like *cycling: interest, female: gender, sports: interest, Melbourne: location*. I think this is called named entity extraction, but I'm not sure. I tried [Stanford Named Entity Recognizer](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/ner/process) and it didn't give me quite what I wanted. The most important things are personal attributes, such as gender, age, interests etc. and it missed most of these on different samples.

Is there any tool/library (preferably in Python) that can help me do this? I know about NLTK, but I don't know how/if I can utilize it here.

Comment: Check if this package helps you...
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geograpy

Answer (score 0):

Normally the Stanford Named Entity Tagger have some default classifiers it's only have some general tagging like `'Name','Location','Organizations'`. If you need to some other tagging you have to  train your own classifier. You can refer [this for create new classifier](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.html#a). I have created custom model and working fine.